# Not found Https request to http redirect using htaccess or other method

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, redirect, https

My htaccess file look like below:

```
# BEGIN_WOERP__
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# handle robots.txt request
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots.txt [L]

RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ /core/sitemap/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(static|static/.*)$
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# END_WOERP__

# enable expirations
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On  
ExpiresDefault "access XXXXXX"
</IfModule>
```

I have separate servers for local development and production server both servers have same htaccess file(above file). when production server didn't redirect https to http page but development server worked correctly(when https didn't find for given url then redirect to http)

1. Please explain why same configuration htaccess setting gave two deference reactions.
2. What will i do for https(not found https request) redirect to http in production server?

Comment: Do you have a SSL certificate and IP on your production server that points to your domain ? Do you have the SSL access configured on your virtualhost ?

Comment: @Prix im sure SSL certificate inside server. some https url work fine. but i don't have any feeling about Vhost in side server. i don't have access for Apache httpd.conf file

Comment: Then I suggest you to start from there, ask your host to provide you with how your domain vhost is configure and replicate that on your local server so you can see how it would work to make the needed adjustments you need.